# Data migration using ethereum with solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I will do operations such as writing and transporting data with an ethereum network using Solidity. And no one should see this moved data, so I have to prove the confidentiality of the data with the logs. How can I do this?

Comment: `And no one should see this moved data` public blockchains are by definition public, so they are unlikely suitable for the purpose. Also your question is XYProblem, so please tell more context for the issue to make it answerable https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

> And no one should see this moved data

Its impossible to prevent people from seeing data on ethereum since all data on a blockchain is public. However, you can send **obfuscated** data by encrypting it using something like [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). This will *hide* the data, and only people who have the decryption keys can read it.